# How can i use Localize in Function or property polymerJS using app-localize-behavior

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Localization behavior is working fine for me, but i don't know if i can use it in a ready function and how.

If I use `{{localize('greeting')}}` in html, Its working fine. But I need to use through function

```
initErrorMessage: function(loc) {
  return localize(loc);
},
```

And I need to use in property as well.

```
datePickerRangeArray: {
    type: Array,
    value: function() {
      return [
        {"key": "!h8", "val": this.localize('last8hrs')},
        {"key": "!h12", "val": this.localize('last12hrs')},
        {"key": "!h24", "val": this.localize('last24hrs')},
        {"key": "!h168", "val": this.localize('last48hrs')},
        {"key": "current-day", "val": this.localize('CurrentDay')},
        {"key": "previous-day", "val": this.localize('PreviousDay')}];
    }
  }
```

I am getting error on this. How to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of error You are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.async function and initialize with  empty object and add localization in attached function with async function.

```
datePickerRangeArray: {
    type: Array,
    value: {}
  }


attached: function(){
   this.async(function(){
     datePickerRangeArray = [
        {"key": "!h8", "val": this.localize('last8hrs')},
        {"key": "!h12", "val": this.localize('last12hrs')},
        {"key": "!h24", "val": this.localize('last24hrs')},
        {"key": "!h168", "val": this.localize('last48hrs')},
        {"key": "current-day", "val": this.localize('CurrentDay')},
        {"key": "previous-day", "val": this.localize('PreviousDay')}];
    },10);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using it in `attached` instead of `ready` as `Polymer` does not guarantee `attributes'`, `children's` availability in ready callback.